# Подсветка карты и нас. пунктов (svg), выбор региона и населенного пункта из списка (БД). Как их подружить?

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, svg

**SVG-карта:**

- **И**меются 5 районов, их id и стили, которые я умею изменять hover'ом

```svg
<path d="***" id="1_rc" *** style="fill:#3fd2df;fill-opacity:1;stroke:none" />
```

- **И**меются 5 районных центров, которые по умолчанию обозначены точками:

```svg
<path d="***" id="3_1"  **** style="fill:#5b5c61;fill-opacity:1" />
```

- **И** их наименования, которые по умолчанию скрыты:

```svg
<text xml:space="preserve" style="***;fill-opacity:0;***" *** id="rcnb" ****>
    <tspan sodipodi:role="line" id="rcnb4_1" *** style="font-size:2.5px">Новобелокатай</tspan>
</text>
```

- **Х.Т**уча населенных пунктов, обозначенные на карте точками, которые по умолчанию скрыты с соответствующими id, согласующиеся с оными в БД:

```svg
<path d="***" id="2_8" *** style="fill:#5b5c61;fill-opacity:0" /><path>
```

**Вывод списка районов и в подпунктах - их населенных пунктов:**
Все id *в БД согласованы с соответствующими областями на карте* и населенными пунктами ***для подсветки при выборе из списка***. Выведу их через выпадающие списки.

**Вопрос:**
Как это сделать? - подсветку соответствующих областей на карте? Возможно ли только средствами css? Если необходим JS, то подскажите код, я сам подстроюсь под него... не программист, увы, а надо вот. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

svg карта у тебя должны быть подключена как object на странице, примерно так:

```
<object data="/common/img/map.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="karta" width="1000" ></object>
```

получить доступ к областям карты можно с помощью jQuery

```
var svgobject = document.getElementById('karta'); // Находим тег <object>
var svgdom = jQuery(svgobject.contentDocument);  // Получаем доступ к объектной модели SVG-файла
```

а далее уже можно просто красить нужные области карты

```
function colorize(id, color)
{
    $(id, svgdom).attr('fill', color);
}
```

Соответственно нужно указать id области карты, color, цвет которым нужно залить область.

Comment: спасибо за направление! как сделаю то, что хотел, отпишусь!